# How to pass parameters to Windows Scheduled Task?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I need to pass parameters to PowerShell script that runs using  Windows Scheduled Task.
Scheduled Task runs from Azure pipeline using cmd `Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "ExampleTask*"` command

[Scheduled Task image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkGR2.png)

Scheduled Task has PS script like this:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $var
)

echo $var
```

And I need to change `$var` dynamically from Azure DevOps pipeline.
Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Set-ScheduledTask` to update the existed ScheduledTask with dynamic variables from Azure Pipeline task. See below steps.

1, Create variables in your azure pipeline, change the variable type to secret if it is credential. See below: i created **User**, **Password**, **DynamicVariable** in the pipeline

[image]

2, Add a powershell task in your pipeline to update your existed ScheduledTask.

I set the **Arguments** in my scheduled task as this:  `-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\test\scheduled.ps1" -var "$(DynamicVariable)"'`

See below script in the Powershell task.

```
#update the Argument with variable defined in the pipeline $(DynamicVariable)
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\test\scheduled.ps1" -var "$(DynamicVariable)"' 

#update the scheduled task
Set-ScheduledTask -Password "$(Password)" -User "$(User)" -TaskName "PipelineTask" -Action $Action

Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask"
```

If you want to set the variable `DynamicVariable` dynamically in the pipeline. You can use [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) `"##vso[task.setvariable variable..]..`.

Add another powershell task before above powershell task to run below commands:

`echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DynamicVariable]newValue"`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I like this approach, but are there some methods how to use a secret variable from Azure Pipeline in PS script that runs with SchedulerTask? For example, if I would use Password in PS script

Comment: You just pass the secret variable (eg. Password) defined in your azure pipeline to the `$Action`.  `New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\test\scheduled.ps1" -var "$(Password)"'`

Comment: yeah, but when I pass the secret variable like this, it becomes visible in TaskScheduler Actions section

Comment: You can have a try mapping the secret variable in the powershell task. For example mapping it to env variable MyPassword in the powershell task `MyPassword = $(Password)`, Then pass the env variable `$env:MyPassword` to the $Action `New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\test\scheduled.ps1" -var "$env:MyPassword"'`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) for more information

Comment: What happens when 2 separate calls try to update the same scheduled task's Dynamic variable at the same time? Wouldn't that cause a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Configure it like this;

**Program/Script :** %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

**Arguments :** -c "C:\script.ps1 -var thevalue"

**script.ps1 :**

```
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $var
    )
    
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("This is the Message text : " + $var)
```

When there are spaces in path or arguments, any of the following quotation variations could be used;

```
-c "& 'c:\script.ps1'" -var 'the param'

-c "& ""c:\script.ps1""" -var 'the param'
```

For quotes in arguments;

```
-c "& ""c:\script.ps1""" -var 'the x\"x''param'
-c "& ""c:\script.ps1""" -var 'the x"""x''param'
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, I would like to change variable directly from Azure Pipeline task, which triggers already existed ScheduledTask using Start-ScheduledTask command. But as I understand in your approach you directly set variable value in Arguments field, but it a bit unsafety, because if I want to pass some credentials here they would be visible.